# Data SIM card offers/prices in Buenos Aires

Tags: cellphones, argentina, data-plans, buenos-aires

I'm traveling to Buenos Aires, Argentina for two weeks and I cannot disconnect from the internet. I will need a data SIM card with more than 2GB (I don't need calls). I searched here, but there is no up-to-date information.

Is there anyone who lives there and can tell me what my options are? Offers and prices will be great!

Comment: Very good question, I'm returning there tomorrow and this info would be useful to me too. Why do some people (who undoubtedly are *not* in Argentina currently) want to close it?

Comment: I think this is very much on-topic. Staying communicated is an essential part of traveling.

Comment: The emphasis on "offers" and "prices" make it sound quite shopping-y. If your real question is "How to get a SIM in Argentina?" you can ask just that; it would probably be received better.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Tuenti is your best bet. They're probably the cheapest provider and have everything pretty much automated. Just buy a SIM card (should be around ~1USD probably) in a kiosk or somewhere, follow instructions and you're almost set. You might even get one for free if you walk around long enough.

Afterwards you should top-up online, which will start a "combo". There's currently a "monthly" combo for $190 (~8USD) which will get you 2.5GiB to use in 30 days, plus 100 minutes (but who cares). There's also a "super monthly" for $290 which gets you 5GiB.

Coverage and speed are as good, if not better, than any other company. I use it daily, sometimes intensively, without any issue. It will also work in the entire country, but I don't think it works abroad, even in neighboring countries.

They used to have a list of places where you could get a SIM card in their website (https://www.tuenti.com.ar/solicita-chip-sim-gratis/puntos-retiro/) but it doesn't seem to be working. By asking in kiosks/minimarkets you should easily find one.

Hope you enjoy Buenos Aires. Be sure to visit the pizzerias.